# Time format adding six hours

Tags: php, apache

I’m having an issue calculating the difference between two time. Here’s my code.

```
<?php
$Now = date('h:i:s');
echo 'Now is: '. $Now . '<br>';
$time1 = strtotime('01:22:24');
$time2 = strtotime('01:28:24');
$diff = $time2 - $time1;
echo 'Time 1: '.date('h:i:s', $time1).'<br>';
echo 'Time 2: '.date('h:i:s', $time2).'<br>';
if($diff){echo 'Difference: '.date('h:i:s', $diff);
}else{echo 'No Difference.';}
?>
```

What it outputs is

Now is: 03:07:01
Time 1: 01:22:24
Time 2: 01:28:24
Difference: 06:06:00

The time “Now is:” is the correct time. The timezone in my php.ini is set to US/Central and I’ve even tried America/Chicago but no help.  I’m running PHP 5.3.5 with apache 2.0 
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: difference between 01:22:24 and 01:28:24 is not 6 hours 6 mins, its just 6 mins !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `date` function takes a UNIX timestamp as its second argument. UNIX timestamps are seconds since January 1, 1970. So when you pass in `$diff` as the second argument to `date`, it is interpreting that as seconds since January 1, 1970 and then displaying the hour, minute and date components of that date!

You should look into using https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php instead. Here is the code using these classes:

```
<?php

$time1 = new DateTime('01:22:24');
$time2 = new DateTime('01:28:24');

if ($time1 == $time2) {
    echo 'No Difference.';
} else {
    $diff = $time2->diff($time1);
    echo 'Difference: ' . $diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to output a difference that's expressed in seconds as a date value.

The difference should be expressed as:

```
if($diff){echo 'Difference: '.$diff . " seconds";
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of $diff is a number of seconds. When you use date however you're localising the time which in this case is adding 6 hours.

Use gmdate instead.

https://www.php.net/gmdate

```
if($diff){echo 'Difference: '.gmdate('h:i:s', $diff);
```